# Tap-to-Click is Shown, but Can't Be Toggled

Tags: kde, touchpad, plasma5

The touchpad on my laptop is a poor design, because it doesn't recede down into its housing to avoid my thenar and hypothenar's proclivity for inadvertent tap-to-clicks.

In Ubuntu 19.10, using this same laptop, I was able to toggle off "Tap to Click", as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135765/256054).

However, in Kubuntu 20.04, this option is grayed out (disabled), and cannot be Toggled:

[image]

Is there another way that I might disable Tap-to-Click, given that the GUI isn't offering the ability to toggle this setting?

Comment: [bug 420762](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420762)

Comment: I have the same issue.  Dell XPS9360 running Kubuntu 20.04.  
I see you filed a bug on this [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420762).
You added a comment to you bug report that there is a workaround but that just links back to this page where I do not see any mention of a workaround.  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: @rodoherty1 : No, you're not missing anything. I anticipated someone here would have provided a workaround quickly, but it hasn't happened yet. Sorry for the confusion; you can't edit bug comments at KDE.

Comment: Thanks @Lonniebiz.
The only thoughts I can add are that the "Tap to Click" option appeared yesterday in my settings window.  I had recently gone through the steps to set up multi-touch trackpad support as described [in this Ansible role](https://github.com/rodoherty1/bootstrap-my-linux-laptop/blob/master/roles/multi-touch-support/tasks/main.yml).  The entire [Ansible playbook](https://github.com/rodoherty1/bootstrap-my-linux-laptop) is one that I use to quickly refresh my Ubuntu laptop.  So I noticed that after multi-touch had been enabled, the "Tap to Click" option was enabled. :shrug:

Comment: @rodoherty1 Now, [my Tap-to-click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Vqt.png) is also enabled. The only thing I've done lately is regular system updates. As you can see, some things are still "shown but disabled", but they're not any things I'm accustom to having anyway. Perhaps this is KDE's way of giving a sneak preview of things to come?

Comment: The reason all those other features are disabled, is because they are all sub-features dependent on Tap-to-click being enabled. If you enable Tap-to-Click, those features too can be toggled. - [Source](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420762#c3)

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. Tap-to-Click can't be enabled. The checkbox is disabled. So, those other features aren't relevant until the first checkbox can be enabled. The bug thread just says it _became_ enabled, but never explains how. It's not due to recent updates. My system has all the most recent updates and the checkbox is not enabled.

Comment: @Vince I just took a look at my Tap-to-click settings, and I too was unable to toggle that check box due to it being disabled. I enabled the ability to toggle it in an unusual way. Basically, I click the "Default" button on the bottom-left, but I did NOT apply it. Instead, I exited out of the Touchpad settings window. Upon doing that it ask me if I wanted to save the changes I made, and clicked "Discard". After that, I went back into the touchpad settings again (from a freshly launched window) and for some reason the "Tap-to-click" became toggleable.

Comment: See [comment 5](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420762#c5). @Vince

Answer (score 15):

Referance: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179275/enable-tap-to-click-kubuntu

I had to add `Option "Tapping" "True"` to the entry `MatchIsTouchpad` in the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`. The exact name of the file might be different for other people.

In the end, the relevant section will look like something like this:

```
Section "InputClass"

        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "Tapping" "True"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

You need to be root to edit the file and reboot your system after the changes!

Comment: This is not Kubuntu specific, seen and fixed it in Fedora.

Comment: This did not work for me, using Kubuntu 22.04, trying to disable tap to click via setting False and rebooting... no change observed

Comment: Still works in 2023) Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I had this same issue on a Razer Blade 15 (mid-2021) running Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The fix for me was to install the synaptics touchpad driver.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Reboot

Comment: For Ubuntu based distributions the right answer. In KDE Neon (22.04LTS) it activates tap-to-click by default and the Touchpad settings page is totally renewed with many more settings.

Comment: Can confirm for Kubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo T580

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue on my Acer Swift 3 Laptop running Kubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 4):

Currently, June 2022, using *Arch Linux* with *KDE/Plasma* desktop environment, to solve the issue simply install the generic driver for *X.Org*, based on `libinput`, and reboot the system:

```
sudo pacman -S xf86-input-libinput
```

Or the specific Synaptics driver:

```
sudo pacman -S xf86-input-synaptics
```

**EDIT**: On october 2022 I've realized that the above did not work anymore on Arch Linux with KDE/Plasma. Consider also that *xf86-input-synaptics* is no longer actively updated (See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchpad_Synaptics) and it is advised to use *libinput* instead.

Installing both the *libinput* and the *libinput-gestures* (this is from AUR) packages on Arch Linux, definetely solved the issue:

Install the former with:

```
sudo pacman -S libinput
```

and the latter with an AUR helper:

```
yay -S libinput-gestures
```

Answer (score 2):

My reputation does not allow me to comment to [the answer by @Dimutha](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630864/547497), so posting as an answer:

follow the instructions from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630864/547497), but use

```
        Option "Tapping" "on"
```

i.e., use `"on"` instead of `"True"`.

I'm running plasmashell 5.24.6, KDE Framework 5.92.0, Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

For people on Fedora, AlmaLinux, Rocky and others RedHat distros.

Put the below in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf note that the file should not be empty.  Further info can be found here https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/enable-touchpad-click/

```
Section  "InputClass"
    Identifier  "touchpad overrides"
    # This makes this snippet apply to any device with the "synaptics" driver
    # assigned
    MatchDriver  "synaptics"

    ####################################
    ## The lines that you need to add ##
    # Enable left mouse button by tapping
    Option  "TapButton1"  "1"
    # Enable vertical scrolling
    Option  "VertEdgeScroll"  "1"
    # Enable right mouse button by tapping lower right corner
    Option "RBCornerButton" "3"
    ####################################

EndSection
```

Comment: The linked page describes how to *enable* touchpad click. *This* question asks how to *disable* it. Why do you believe that the instructions that you quote will do what this question asks for?

Comment: It makes the option toggleable in the UI so you can turn it off using this method. You could also change the value to 0 instead of 1.